# Fail Jenkins fast for any failures in parallel Jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am running many Functions in parallel in Jenkins and if one of the Function fails, Jenkins will wait for other parallel processes/functions to complete. How do I fail fast for any errors.

For example:

I am calling function1 and function2  from my Jenkins workflow as

```
parallel 
Function1call: {
    function1( commit, option1 )}, 
Function2call: {
    function2( commitdb, option2 )
}
```

The function1 fails immediately but it will wait for function2 to complete.

How do I fail the job immediately in case of any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow 1.4+ has a `failFast` option for this purpose.